# How to show or hide when filter is on in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app which is built on AngularJS.

i want to remove a button when the filter is on. Can any one please check the below code for me ?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter/Search" ng-model="mtgFilter">

<div ng-repeat="items in elements | filter:mtgFilter">
   {{items.name}}
</div> 

<input type="Button" value="Save" ng-show="mtgFilter == ''" />
```

Regards,
Fresher

Comment: What do you mean by filter is on ?

Comment: when i type something in 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Filter/Search" ng-model="mtgFilter">

i want the button to be hidden

Comment: I guess it is already happen in your code http://plnkr.co/edit/D3mD2Cju1ESf4XyzTSSN?p=preview

Comment: I am assuming you need to hide the button in case of their is result in search and you want to show the 'save' button in case of no result in filter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/D3mD2Cju1ESf4XyzTSSN?p=preview

Comment: thanks @squiroid this is what i am looking at, but, as my list is generated dynamically generated, ng-hide="!(elements|filter:mtgFilter).length" is not working for me.

Is there any other work around ??

Comment: or its not working because i have the button in ng-include ?

Comment: Hey i created it with dynamic data and ng-include "http://plnkr.co/edit/D3mD2Cju1ESf4XyzTSSN?p=preview"

Comment: Did you find any other problem in your code ?

Comment: @squiroid looks like there is some issue in my code i will check from my end .. thanks a lot for your help and support :)

Comment: great check it. If the problem still not resolved post your complete code with demo(fiddle or plunker) :-)

Comment: Hi @squiroid i tried my best to create a plunker link please find it below.
http://plnkr.co/edit/DGbI0PXyiEE9cjq03VnE?p=preview

i dont no how ng-route will work in plunker, please take a look at app.js and footer.html  ( app is not giving any ui output in plunker)

Comment: Here is the working plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/WgFNXJhUVkyFkoJsWiVV?p=preview your plunker consists lots of small error's i removed them and little addition.

Comment: if i do {{mtgFilter}} in footer its not binding anything in the app, but, its working fine on plunker... any idea why this behavior ??

Comment: No idea!! May be you can use this $parent.mtgFilter.

Comment: wahoo .. $parent.mtgFilter worked finally :) thanks a ton @squiroid

Comment: Glad to help you out please upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding to @squiroid's words

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter/Search" ng-model="$parent.mtgFilter">

<div ng-repeat="items in elements | filter:mtgFilter">
   {{items.name}}
</div> 

<input type="Button" value="Save" ng-show="$parent.mtgFilter == ''" />
```

should work ..

Comment: I got -13 bounty for my words :-P

Answer (score 0):

By filter is on do you mean when some text is entered in the filter text box ? Then you can use the `mtgFilter` model to decide what buttons to hide and which ones to show.

```
ng-show="mtgFilter == ''"
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the answer to your question :-)

```
 <li ng-hide="(elements | filter:mtgFilter).length != elements.length">Save</li>
```

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WgFNXJhUVkyFkoJsWiVV?p=preview) for you